# Adding Google/OSM/Bing etc. style map layer to QGIS

Tags: qgis, mapping, heat-map, united-states, basemap

I am aiming to create a heat map of Census tracts in Georgia based on population. I have all of the data - the population for each census tract in Georgia.

I've been able to create the heat map successfully by importing a census tract shapefile and following this tutorial: http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/03/using-tabular-data-in-qgis.html

However I am stuck on how to add a nice looking map layer underneath which will show common geographical features - highways, cities, water courses etc. I have tried importing OSM data from cloudmade but there is far too much detail. The map is supposed to be fairly high level but the shapefiles from there show every single road. I am trying to replace MS MapPoint (no 2010 census tracts). The functionality I am trying to get would allow for different levels of detail depending on how far I zoom. Generally just showing major roads / cities etc. I don't mind if this is automatic or manual.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Right. It seems that just articulating my problem in the question above was enough to get my brain working down the right path.

The OpenLayers plugin does exactly what I want. It will allow me to add Google/OSM layers to QGIS.

Instructions here: http://www.lib.uwaterloo.ca/locations/umd/documents/QGISGuide_Qian.pdf

Openlayers Plugin details here: https://github.com/sourcepole/qgis-openlayers-plugin

I hope that helps anyone who is searching the web with a similar problem.

Comment: I have just managed to tweak the OpenLayers Plugin in order to [load a styled Google Maps](http://gistncase.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/how-to-add-google-maps-styled-layer-in.html) in Qgis 2. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

Some options:

1. Use the [OpenLayers Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/openlayers_plugin/).  This plugin allows you to use Google, Bing or OSM's tiles as background image.
2. Create a custom vector style similar to Google or OSM. [Underdark](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/187/underdark) made a series of post on how to do this with OSM data using the [New Symbology Rule based rendering](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/09/16/google-maps-styled-road-maps-in-qgis/).  She even provided the [qml in github.](https://github.com/anitagraser/QGIS-resources/)

Answer (score 2):

The OpenLayers Plugin is intended to provide numerous background maps in Qgis such as Google Maps or Terrain. Anyway, sometimes Google is not suitable for your needs, because its style [conflicts](http://spatialityblog.com/2010/05/21/thoughts-about-google-map-styles/) with your overlays.

For this reason, I managed to tweak the OpenLayers Plugin in order to [load Google Maps styled](http://gistncase.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/how-to-add-google-maps-styled-layer-in.html), allowing you to display your own customized Google Maps just as the other Google layers.

Be aware that Google tiles resolution is quite poor for printing.

Answer (score 0):

**QuickMapServices** plugin will give you LOTS of base maps. More info:

https://nextgis.com/blog/quickmapservices/

https://opengislab.com/blog/2018/4/15/add-basemaps-in-qgis-30